# CSS3 in Jquery - Nth-Child

Tags: jquery, css, css-selectors

Is it possible to convert an advanced css 3 nth-child selector into jquery for ie8? I know that you can use nth-child but my jQuery skills are very limited.

Thank you for any response

```
.clients .gallery a:nth-child(3n+3) {
    margin-right: 0;
}
```

Comment: Although it is possible, it will be quite slow if you have to deal with a big amount of childs. If possible, I would recommend you to play with classes instead on the generated HTML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes.

CSS

```
.clients .gallery a:nth-child(3n+3), .ie8-gallery-nth-child {
    margin-right: 0;
}
```

JS (wrap this in conditional comments targeting IE<9

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".clients .gallery a:nth-child(3n+3)").addClass("ie8-gallery-nth-child")
});
```

**Note:** any time the elements that it's targeting changes, you'll need to remove said class and re-add it to the correct elements.

Comment: Thank you, is there an effecient way to wrap this rule in the same way? .grid4 .col:nth-of-type(4n+1),
.grid3 .col:nth-of-type(3n+1),
.grid2 .col:nth-of-type(2n+1),
.grid1-4 .col:nth-of-type(4n+1)

Comment: Yeah, it would be near identical. One more comma and the ie8only class, then use the selector without the ieonly class to target the elements and add the class. It won't be efficient though. There really isn't anything you can do with javascript to make it efficient.

Answer (score 2):

It's pretty much just like css:

`var nthChildren = $('.clients .gallery a:nth-child(3n+3)');`